# Mysql count returns empty while using groupby

Tags: mysql

This question asked many times in stack overflow before.I tried all solutions,But none of them helps.

my query is :-

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  
  table_campaign_referralmail t1 
  INNER JOIN table_user_information t2 ON t1.refferal_id=t2.user_id 
  GROUP BY t1.refferal_id
```

**return empty results**

t1 is empty,t2 has some records

**Tried query and result**

```
SELECT CASE  WHEN COUNT(*) IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE COUNT(*) END 
FROM   table_campaign_referralmail t1 INNER JOIN table_user_information t2 ON 
t1.refferal_id=t2.user_id GROUP BY t1.refferal_id
```

**return empty results**

`COALESCE(count(*),0)` instant of count(*)

**return empty results**

`COUNT(t1.*)` instant of count(*)

**return error result**

*Edit*

t2 has the basic info of user. t1 is the referral table.so, it has number of user
referred friends. so it may comes multiple times.
like

```
refferal_id  friend_id 
   1            2
   1            3
```

so, i want to display number of referrals per user

like

```
user_id   number of referal
1               2
```

This is what i am doing .

please advise me thanks

Comment: If t1 is empty, how do you expect a group by on one of its columns to be meaningful?

Answer (score 0):

*"t1 is empty,t2 has some records"* of course it will return empty, because you are doing an `INNER JOIN`. How will you count the `t1` records grouped by `refferal_id` if there ain't any in it?

Tell us what you want to do, and we might come up with a re-arranged query to do just the thing you want to do.

Comment: @gowri: "t2 is the referral table" did you mean "t1 is the referral table"? Please confirm, do both tables have records or not? If one of the tables doesn't have any record, then your `INNER JOIN` query will always return an empty result.

Comment: t1 is refferal table, when t1 is empty i got problem .How can i modify my query

Comment: @gowri: You can modify the query like @Imre L, to return the user information, but if you don't have any referrals your rows will always return 0.

Answer (score 0):

this will get you number of referrals per user:

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.refferal_id)
  FROM table_user_information t2
  LEFT JOIN table_campaign_referralmail t1 ON t1.refferal_id=t2.user_id 
 GROUP BY t2.user_id
```

Comment: L:it returns 0 but with several rows

Comment: @gowri: the above query is correct and should give you the desired result. Why it is giving you 0 count for all users is because there seem to be no records in table table_user_information, as you have also mentioned in your post that "t1 is empty"; so this means that the referral count is 0 for each user. Hope this makes sense. Please suggest if that is not the case and if possible give a snapshot of your data.